# Примитивное окно загрузки приложения

Tags: c++

Посоветуйте библиотеку для создания примитивного окна загрузки приложения.

(Без консоли)

```
______________________________________________
|                                            |
|                 Loading...78%              |
|____________________________________________|
```

Comment: Если "без консоли", то приложение с GUI? Если да, какой библиотекой это гуи сделано? Не получится ей же сделать окно загрузки?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, просто пример, неважно какая GUI библиотека

Comment: Не понял. Почему неважно? Если вы уже используете какую-то библиотеку для гуи, почему не хотите ей же создать окно загрузки? Это же самый простой вариант.

Comment: на winapi подойдет?

Comment: @helldrg, да...

Comment: Сейчас тогда, придумаю, как красиво и наглядно оформить и отвечу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В инициализации элементов управления добавляете:

```
int countItem = 1000; //Для примера переберем 1000 элементов
int countStep = 10;   //10 раз будет меняться значение прогресс бара
InitCommonControls(); // инициализирует класс элемента управления, в данном случае прогресс бар

HWND pBar = CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER| PBS_SMOOTH,
  10, 10, 100, 30, window, 0, instance, NULL);//создаем прогресс бар

SendMessage(pBar, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(0, 10)); //устанавливаем диапазон
SendMessage(pBar, PBM_SETSTEP, (WPARAM)1, 0);//устанавливаем шаг
UpdateWindow(pBar);//отрисовываем окно

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (i % (countItem / countStep) == 0)
    {
        Sleep(1000);// 10 раз сюда зайдет программа, если элементы управления не будут реагировать 
//на действия не пугайтесь, на практике вместо этой команды вы будете выполнять какие то, нужные 
//вам действия
        SendMessage(pBar, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);//продвигает значения прогресс бара на шаг
    }
}
```